# uwp adaptive gridview renders 1st element wrong

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I am using **AdaptiveGridView** from **UWP Community toolkit**.
The Very first Item displays horribly wrong and all other Items are displayed just fine.

See in the picture below the 1st item has bigger Folder Image than others.

[image: see the 1st item with red line around it]

**XAML**

```
<Style TargetType="controls:AdaptiveGridView" x:Key="MainAdaptiveStyle">
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="StretchContentForSingleRow" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="DesiredWidth" Value="220"/>
    <Setter Property="IsItemClickEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="animations:ReorderGridAnimation.Duration" Value="400"/>
</Style>


<PivotItem Header="Folders">
    <controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="FoldersLibraryGridView"
                               Style="{StaticResource MainAdaptiveStyle}"
                               ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Folders}">
        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate  x:DataType="data:FolderItem">
                <userTemplates:FolderTemplate />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
</PivotItem>
```

<....below is user control which is used the DataTemplate, known as **FolderTemplate**...>

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="ThumbImageStyle" >
            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="UniformToFill"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="ThumbImage" Grid.Row="0">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </Border.Background>
        <Image  Source="ms-appx:///Assets/FolderIcon.png"    

                Style="{StaticResource ThumbImageStyle}"
                />
    </Border>
    <Border Background="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}" Grid.Row="1" Padding="8,0,4,0">
        <TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind FolderItem.MyFolder.DisplayName}"
                    Style="{StaticResource GridViewVideoName}"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**UPDATE**
as You can see in the picture below, market with red line, right side of each item is faded where the folder name textblock ends, and this occurs only when ItemHeight is Explicitly set on the **ApativeGridView**

[image: faded problem]

Comment: Change the `VerticalAlignment` to `Top` in `ThumbImageStyle`?

Comment: @AVK I tried that, that doesn't help

Comment: Can you create a repo?

Comment: here you go @JustinXL  . You will need some folders in your video library which would be rendered in this sample. 
https://github.com/touseefbsb/gridviewfirstItemSample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the fix is simple. First have a look at the description of this control on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/49194225b6bb1922f322210b8b05abc240c6e571/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/AdaptiveGridView/AdaptiveGridView.cs#L26) -

> ```
> /// <remarks>
> /// The number and the width of items are calculated based on the
> /// screen resolution in order to fully leverage the available screen space. The property ItemsHeight define
> /// the items fixed height and the property DesiredWidth sets the minimum width for the elements to add a
> /// new column.</remarks>
> ```

I believe **ItemsHeight** is a typo there. It really should be `ItemHeight`. You just need to specify it (e.g. `<controls:AdaptiveGridView ItemHeight="280" ... />` and the problem should go away.

---

### Update

Your second issue is related to the `DropShadowPanel` in the toolkit. If you resize the window a bit you will notice that the shadows then render properly.

I had a look at the default style of the control and the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property is set to `Left` initially. So it looks like the control doesn't properly resize its inner shadow component when the size is changed.

But since you have already got a local style, you can just set it to `Stretch` and the issue should go away.

```
<Style TargetType="controls:DropShadowPanel"
       x:Key="MainDropShadow">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
```

---

### Update 2

OK, so here is the reason why initially the shadow is not stretching -

The shadow size is calculated based on the `Content` of the `DropShadowPanel` control, but the shadow only monitors the `SizeChanged` event of the control to update its size.

What's happening in your case is that your `Grid` (direct child of the `DropShadowPanel` control) was initially arranged with a smaller size, then the shadow size was set, and then when the size of your `Grid` updates, because the size of `DropShadowPanel` is still with the same size, no `SizeChanged` will be invoked, hence the shadow size is not re-calculated. If you have the toolkit source code, you should be able to simply switch to monitor the `SizeChanged` of the `Content` instead and the problem should go away.

When you are setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`, you are effectively saying "the child should have the same size of the parent". So when the shadow is initially sized, your `Grid` is already at the same size of its parent. But I feel like they must have been using `Left` for a reason and this should just be a temporary fix for your case.

Comment: When I set the ItemHeight it gets fixed, so when I resize the window only width is changing ( responsively ) and height remains same. Which sint a good user experience. I am using it with same properties and no ItemHeight Set on another location but there I am using thumbnails of the videos and in that case the 1st Item also looks same as others

Comment: No, whether you set it or not, the height will be changing. Just set it and compare without setting it. The outcome is the same except the first item renders fine with it set.

Comment: I have updated the repository please have a look, there is another problem now right side of each item is faded (with respect to auto length of the textblock ) with dark or white color depending upon the requested theme of the page you can switch the theme on MainPage.xaml to see the change, I am attaching a photo indicating the problem in the updated question, and I am commiting the changed version of the sample to the repo, Please have a look :) Note that this faded problem only occurs when itemHeight is set.