# GridView item height is fixed

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am working on a project where I have a `GridView` and I need to show an image and 3 `TextBlock`s. The image has a fixed `Height` and `Width` properties and the first `TextBlock` have either 1 line of text or 2. The other `TextBlock`s have only 1 line of text.

The problem is that if the first `TextBlock` has 1 line of text everything is shown perfectly but if the text is longer than one line the last `TextBlock` is not shown in the `GridViewItem` and it is pushed down where it gets hidden.

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding HomeList, Mode=OneWay}">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ItemHelper">
            <UserControl>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="image" Source="{x:Bind ItemImage}"
                           Height="144" Width="256" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="title" Text="{x:Bind ItemTitle}" Style="{StaticResource OneLinedItemTitle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="section" Text="{x:Bind ItemSection}"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="pubUpdate" Text="{x:Bind ItemPublishTime}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I have also tried the above XAML with `RelativePanel` and the same thing happens. I want the height to be fixed at max height with 2 lines of text for `title` or adjustable for each item in the `GridView`.

[image: image 1]

As you can see that the first item shows 3 `TextBlock`s but the 2nd item shows only 2 where the first one has 2 lines of text.

I only see the following possible options:

1. Set the height of the `StackPanel` to be fixed for the max height of the items
2. Set the height of the `title` to be fixed with 2 lines of text
3. Maybe editing the default `Style` for `GridViewItem` would help

Or maybe there is any other possible option which doesn't involve setting the fixed height for any element.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with the last `TextBlock` when the first `TextBlock` has two line? (Say about the position of last `TextBlock`)

Comment: It should be visible on the screen. Thats the problem basically, it gets hidden if the first TextBlock has 2 lines.

Comment: So do you want to have `GridView.ItemTemplate` which vary in size?

Comment: Yes if that is possible.

Comment: Take a look at [WrapPanel](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/WrapPanel/). In my opinion, it won't be looking good in your case. So you could set fixed height to your `UserControl`.

Comment: Yes, i am thinking about setting a fixed height to my StackPanel. It would be the better solution but i will look at the WrapPanel to see how it goes.

Comment: Think about this. If you want to show full text, your image will have to be pushed up which results in a smaller image since you are using a StackPanel here. How about using a Grid to host your image and then a child StackPanel aligned bottom to host the text blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `Grid` inside your `UserControl` instead of the `StackPanel`. The `StackPanel` sizes to content `Heights` only. I would use a `Grid`, set the `RowDefinition` at third `Row` to `Height="*"` and the other ones to `Height="Auto"`. I tested this with an `ItemsControl` (that worked...)

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding HomeList, Mode=OneWay}">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ItemHelper">
            <UserControl>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Name="image" Source="{x:Bind ItemImage}"                          Height="144" Width="256" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="title" Text="{x:Bind ItemTitle}" Style="{StaticResource OneLinedItemTitle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Name="section" Text="{x:Bind ItemSection}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Name="pubUpdate" Text="{x:Bind ItemPublishTime}"/>
                </Grid>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. It hides the section part of the template if the title has 2 lines.

Comment: The actual solution is to use a fixed height for parent element, whether it's a `StackPanel` or a `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the first item is not rendering correctly (at least this is what happened to me). Check [Justin XL answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44973459/13386674), maybe it can help. Apparently the problem (from poor rendering) is solved by setting the `ItemHeight` property

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <ItemsWrapGrid  ItemHeight="DesiredHeight"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```